# How to recursively delete all .DS_STORE files from a directory on a Windows Machine?

Tags: python, powershell, .ds-store

I extracted a `.zip` file compressed on a Mac and discovered that the compression included all the `.DS_STORE` meta-directory files (I think used to speed up spotlight search, but besides the point?).

Is there a one-liner I can execute from a Windows PowerShell or simple python script to clean up this folder by recursively deleting these files?

I get the error: `FIND: Parameter format not correct` when using:

```
find . -name '*.DS_Store' -type f -delete
```

Comment: The easiest way would be just to search for the files in Windows Explorer (ctrl-f), highlight them, and then delete them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PowerShell do this:

```
cd MyFolder

Get-ChildItem -recurse -filter .DS_STORE | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

When you specify `-WhatIf`, then PowerShell won't make any changes. It will instead tell you what it would have done. When you are happy with what it will do, then you can remove the `-WhatIf`. (It always pays to be careful when doing a recursive delete. You don't want to delete the wrong things.)

Comment: Only deletes the first .DS_STORE, not the others in the subdirectory

Comment: @tarabyte, sorry, answer updated.

Comment: You might also need to follow it up with `gci -recurse -filter "._*" | del -whatif` to remove HFS garbage.

Answer (score 0):

That [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) syntax you are using in your example seems to me to be more appropriate for Mac OS X or Linux/Unix setups than a Windows setup. Instead, perhaps use the [`del`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771049.aspx) command like this in Windows [as explained here](http://awesometoast.com/delete-all-instances-of-ds_store-in-windows/):

```
del /s /q /f /a:h .DS_STORE
```

Comment: I've tried that too and get the error: `Remove-Item: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '/q'` from the directory of interest and using Windows PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

**Objective:** Remove all occurrences of both ".DS_Store" and "._.DS_Store" in current and all sub-directories under Windows.

Windows "find" utility works differently than Linux "find". I highly recommend you use Cygwin (available [here](https://www.cygwin.com/)). Cygwin provides and makes Linux utilities available under Windows. Once you have Cygwin, you can navigate to the base directory of you choice:

Example: To navigate to the c:\projects, you will run:

```
cd /cygdrive/c/projects
```

Once you're in the folder/directory of your choosing, you can then run the following two commands.

```
# First let's find all occurrences of both ".DS_Store" and "._.DS_Store" (recursive)     
find . -type f \( -name ".DS_Store" -o -name "._.DS_Store" \) -print0

# After we have ensured that the results are good then let's rerun and pipe it to the rm (remove) command via xargs
find . -type f \( -name ".DS_Store" -o -name "._.DS_Store" \) -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

This should now remove all occurrences of those two files from a Windows directory (recursive)

Cheers